# PHP page outputting server error

Tags: php, html, web-services

I am trying to create a page that outputs "no query string" if $_REQUEST is null or if $_REQUEST is not null, output a page that says "query string". Also, output the line "The query string is . var_dump($_REQUEST)."I have written the code, but am not able to get the page to load and do not know where to go from here.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<?php
$req = $_REQUEST;
if($req === null) { ?>
    <title>no query string</title>
    <body>
    <p>The query string is null.</p><br>
    </body>
    <?php
} ?>
<?php
else { ?>
    <title>with a query string</title>
    <body>
    <?php
    $dump = var_dump($_REQUEST);
    echo "The query string is " . $dump;
    ?>
    </body>
    <?php
} ?>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you close an `if` statement, you have to start the `else` without coming out of PHP.

Just remove the closing and opening PHP tags:

```
 </body>
    <?php
} else { ?>
    <title>with a query string</title>
```

Also, `$_REQUEST` will never be null. It will simply be an empty array. Try `empty($_REQUEST)` instead.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I corrected both points on your answer, but I am still getting the server error.

Comment: Ah! I found the error. I had another syntax error and it is working now. Thanks for the answer!